# Why is this batch file crashing?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am attempting to code a program using batch script (I know no other programming language) which saves me time rolling on multiple tables to create a random encounter for a PnP RPG.

The program simulates a d100 roll using

```
set /a nsides=100
set /a d1=%random%%%nsides+1
```

then checks the value of d1 against 100 different if/goto commands arranged thusly

```
if %d1%==1 goto loc1
if %d1%==2 goto loc1
if %d1%==3 goto loc1
if %d1%==4 goto loc2
if %d1%==5 goto loc2
if %d1%==6 goto loc2
if %d1%==7 goto loc3
```

to rout the program to a line of code which sets a new variable t1, to whatever the table says occurs with a roll of d1. Then it routs the program threw the other 2 tables in the process of getting variables t1, t2, and t3 to generate a sentence describing where the encounter is, who the encounter is with, and what takes place.

From what I can tell it usually crashes when finding t3. t3 is a little tricky because sometimes it also generates a number of enemies present. For example
:UL2

```
set /a UL1a="%RANDOM% %% 4"+"%RANDOM% %% 4"+4
set /a UL1b="%RANDOM% %% 8"+"%RANDOM% %% 8"+7
set t3=you come across a battle, %UL1a% settlers are fending off a gang of %UL1b% raiders.
goto display
```

For some reason, I get t3 outputted occasionally as %13324%%nsides+1, yet the program still has a variable for t3 from one of the possible tables when prompted to display all 3 of the the variables. Also sometimes when generating an encounter the entire program crashes to desktop. I am also noticing that it often repetes results from previous generated encounters despite ~3540 different possible ones.

What do I do?

Comment: Definettly, you should take sometime to learn Python - follow the official tutorial in python.org, it will take you less time to learn wat you need to know than to properly type the lines in your last listing.

Comment: Two things come to mind.  `Set "t3="` <-- use that at the start of the loop to initialise t3.  The other thing is to ensure that the text in t3 has no poison characters.  You haven't shown enough code for anyone to check for other errors, or to suggest another way to do it.

Comment: @foxidrive Its a roughly 700 line program... I figured that people would TLDR it if I did. I would greatly appreciate someone else checking for errors if you are willing I could PM it to you some how.

Comment: Post a link to it on `dropbox`

Comment: @foxidrive Here you are https://www.dropbox.com/s/yg9xbpl76029b98/Fallout%20Random%20Encounter%20Generator.bat

Comment: your 700 lines of code will be reduced to half or even lesser by not using batch!

Comment: Can't get it to crash in the manner you've described. Hit the non-existent label `ULT` many times.

Comment: @Magoo Ohhhh.... Thanks! I'll correct that bug. I must have forgotten to ad the T tot he label. Hopefully I can make this thing usefull as intended.

Comment: In at least two spots you have used `set /a t3=` and are using it to set plain text.

Comment: @foxidrive Ah. Thank you. I'll go and fix those. Thank you so much for helping me out!

Comment: You can use `for /l %%x in (1,1,100) do if %d1% == %%x goto loc%%x` to not use as many lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

Are you aware that you could use

```
goto loc%d1%

...

:loc3
:loc2
:loc1
  (your code for "loc1")

:loc6
:loc5
:loc4
  (your code for "loc2")
```

OR

```
if %d1% leq 3 goto loc1
if %d1% leq 6 goto loc2
```

to reduce your `if/then` tally?

Comment: Hang on, what dose the leq command do? Is that how you make it check from 1 to 40 without using 40 individual lines? Becuase if there is a way to make it check a variable against a range of numbers that would be amazing. I think the code may just be too bloated to run properly... Its 1604 lines long...

Comment: `leq` is a comparison operator. It means `less than or equal to` and operates as it reads - if variable is less than or equal to whatever... see `if/?` from the prompt for the full set.

Comment: Thanks! Making that adjustment. At the very least it will mean less scrolling while bug searching.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted explicit and independent control over what each label executes, you could use d1 in the goto command, you would just need to to have each potential roll with a label. This is a *little* bulky.

```
set /a nsides=100
set /a d1=%random%%%nsides+1
goto loc%d1%
:loc1
:loc2
(code for 1/2)
goto end
:loc3
:loc4
(code for 3/4)
goto end
:end
echo app complete
```